# Can I preserve my mediumtext fields when upgrading from 2 to 3?

Tags: mysql

I have had to edit a few fields in my EE install from TEXT to MEDIUMTEXT so that all the content for the entries in the relevant channels will fit.

On a prior upgrade within EE 2.x, there was a database change that meant all the fields were reset to TEXT.

My questions are:

1) Does anyone know if the same will happen when upgrading from 2 to 3?

2) If so, is there anything I can do to prevent these particular fields from being changed?